# Why is "Yismechu VeMalchutcha" omitted in the Shabbat Mincha Amidah (Nusach Sefard)?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, shemoneh-esrei, mincha-afternoon-prayer, nusach-sefard

Nusach Sefard has the paragraph "Yismechu VeMalchutcha" in the Amidah of every tefillah of Shabbat, apart from Mincha.

What is different about Mincha compared with the other tefillot (Arvit, Shacharit, Mussaf) which means that Yismechu VeMalchutcha is not recited?

Comment: I'm curious as to why Nusach Sefard has it during Ma'ariv and Shacharit (although even Nusach Ashkenaz has most of the paragraph during Shacharit, as well. They just omit the 1st sentence.) At any rate, see the end of my answer, here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87448/5275. I have a feeling that Mincha's theme is focused on having the world recognize G-d's kingdom in the future (Mashiach) which conflicts with saying "Let's be happy with his Kingdom" as if all recognized it, already.

Answer (score 3):

[Ta'amei HaMinhagim 390](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=189) writes:

> טעם שאין אומרים ישמחו במלכותך בתפילת מנחה מחמת היות עת פטירת הצדיקים ערבה השמחה
>
> The reason that we don't say *yismechu vemalchutcha* during *minchah* is since it is the time when the righteous passed away, the joy is tempered.

He later specifies that the righteous who passed away on *shabbat* afternoon were Yosef, Moshe and David.